# Easiest way to use skype within Sharepoint?

Tags: wss-3.0

Which is the easiest way to use Skype within Sharepoint (WSS 3.0)

I mean How to integrate it? I mean when I see a sharepoint username...i want it show skype status also. Is it possible?

Any ideas?

-saumil

Comment: Please note this section from our [faq#questions]: "We don't accept questions about commercial products that integrate with, run on top of, or extend the SharePoint platform."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration of Skype with SharePoint can be very useful, e.g. you are reviewing a task list and see an overdue item. With an integration, you can see directly the status of the person and contact him without first having to switch and search. Or what about a group conference/chat with your new team - again without searching, etc.

However, the CodePlex solution is rather limited, and the usual request of status from Skype online slows down page rendering for more than a few names.

We have therefore developed a professional integration of Skype into SharePoint. It allows a whole range of different applications, such as showing status for a large list of people without performance degradation, contacting single persons, as well as starting a Skype conference/chat directly from SharePoint interface. You can find it here: http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5811

Answer (score 1):

In what way do you want to use Skype within SharePoint?

Skype is a client side instant messaging application with VOIP capabilities whereas SharePoint is a storage and presentation platform.

Please elaborate on your requirement.

Comment: How to integrate it? I mean when I see a sharepoint username...i want it show skype status also. Is it possible? Thx

Comment: @saumil Please move this explanation to the original question. However, what you need is *Sharepoint Skype status field* http://skypestatusfield.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Thnks Marek for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

have a read at this forum: http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=49883

Comment: -1 Please do not post link-only answers. If the linked page goes away, this answer would become completely useless. An answer should stand on its own, with the link providing *supplemental* information.